# CoreData equivalent of sum...group by

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have the following pseudo-SQL schema:

```
table flight
  id int primary key
  date timestamp
  aircraft_id int (foreign key to aircraft.id)

table flight_component
  flight_id int (foreign key to flight.id)
  component_id int (foreign key to component.id)
  duration double
```

If I convert this to using CoreData, is there an equivalent way to get the total duration for each component with another query predicate?  I think the SQL equivalent would be

```
select component_id, sum(duration)
from flight_component
join flight on (flight_component.flight_id = flight.id)
where flight.date between ? and ?
group by component_id
```

Or am I going to have to make my query and then sum up all the components myself?

Comment: how to calculate the sum of particular column in core data table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query for @"someArray.@sum". There's a list of such operators on the [Collection Operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-SW7) page.