# Objective C: CoreData and aggregation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, aggregate, core-data

Given a CoreData-Entity with an date (days) and an ammount called Transaction.
Is it with CoreData possible (and how) to aggregate/group the 'table' (with all Transactions) by Date and calculate the sum of the day in a second column/attribute?
(the SQL-Solution would be `SELECT date, sum(ammount) FROM transaction GROUP BY date`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stack Overflow: "CoreData equivalent of sum…group by"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908692/coredata-equivalent-of-sum-group-by)

Answer (score 2):

They may not do exactly what you want, but since Core Data is fully KVC compliant, take a look at the [Key-Value Coding Set and Array operators](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE). This should at least get you pretty close to what you're looking to do.